# Flutter Error: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I am getting this error when trying to run my project

Answer (score 0):

check gradle version in build.gradle file. Downgrade the version or upgrade once.